# Configure Outlook so "Reply" to an item in "Sent Mail" uses the To: list

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

As a GMail user, I much appreciate that when I "reply" to an email sent from me, it knows I want it to replicate the To: field, not move the From: field to the To: field.  Outlook does this if I "Reply All" to an email entry in my "Sent Items" folder, but if I just "Reply", it addresses the message to me.  Is there a way I can tell Outlook to behave like GMail?

Comment: Thunderbird is also clever enough. Outlook 2016 is still "stupid".

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, no. You have to use the "Reply All" button on sent items.